# Can't run commands from local npm packages (webpack, babel, etc) on Windows cmd. Nonexistent cygdrive/c path shows up in error. NOT using cygwin

Tags: windows, npm, cmd, path, package

***EDIT*: Rolling back to npm v3.10.10 solves the problem. Haven't tried other versions. But I cannot use v6.x.x versions... either npm@latest (currently 6.8.0) or npm@next (currently 6.9.0) cause an error. I'd like to know if I'm doing anything wrong myself. I'm just rolling back versions for now, but I'd like to know if it's something I should report or if there's something about npm 6 that I don't know I'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance.**

I was trying to make a simple, barebones webpack 4.x.x setup using npm on Windows 10 cmd console, and I got a very strange error. It turns out it has something to do with running the `webpack` command through `npm run`. I was later able to replicate the very same error trying to run the `babel` command on a completely different project (again, a barebones setup using only babel). Just using a simple command like "echo hello" and running it through `npm run` does NOT yield a problem though. I'm going crazy. Here's the example for webpack, following a basic webpack 4 tutorial:

1. Have npm installed
2. Open the cmd.exe command console
3. Create new empty project folder, cd there
4. `npm init -y`
5. `npm i webpack webpack-cli --save-dev`
6. Edit package.json and add `"build":"webpack"` or `"build":"webpack app.js -o bundle.js"`(doesn't really matter) to the scripts. Create corresponding app.js file with any code inside if you wish, again, the error is the same regardless.
7. `npm run build`

...aaaand I get this error log:

```
/cygdrive/c/Users/Mariano/Desktop/Pruebas/webpack_example/node_modules/.bin/webpack: line 2: sed: command not found
/cygdrive/c/Users/Mariano/Desktop/Pruebas/webpack_example/node_modules/.bin/webpack: line 2: dirname: command not found
/cygdrive/c/Users/Mariano/Desktop/Pruebas/webpack_example/node_modules/.bin/webpack: line 4: uname: command not found
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\webpack\bin\webpack.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:580:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:506:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:741:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:285:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:739:3)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! webpack_example@1.0.0 build: `webpack`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the webpack_example@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Mariano\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-03-03T01_20_05_007Z-debug.log
```

...and here's the full log file from npm-cache\logs:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'build' ]
2 info using npm@6.4.1
3 info using node@v10.13.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
5 info lifecycle webpack_example@1.0.0~prebuild: webpack_example@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle webpack_example@1.0.0~build: webpack_example@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle webpack_example@1.0.0~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle webpack_example@1.0.0~build: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\Mariano\Desktop\Pruebas\webpack_example\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Files\cpp\bin\Intel64;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\PostgreSQL\pg96\bin;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\Mariano\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\;C:\Users\Mariano\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\;C:\Users\Mariano\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Mariano\AppData\Roaming\npm
9 verbose lifecycle webpack_example@1.0.0~build: CWD: C:\Users\Mariano\Desktop\Pruebas\webpack_example
10 silly lifecycle webpack_example@1.0.0~build: Args: [ '-c', 'webpack' ]
11 silly lifecycle webpack_example@1.0.0~build: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle webpack_example@1.0.0~build: Failed to exec build script
13 verbose stack Error: webpack_example@1.0.0 build: `webpack`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:182:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:962:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:251:5)
14 verbose pkgid webpack_example@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\Mariano\Desktop\Pruebas\webpack_example
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "build"
18 verbose node v10.13.0
19 verbose npm  v6.4.1
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error webpack_example@1.0.0 build: `webpack`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the webpack_example@1.0.0 build script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Here's some facts on the matter: If I install webpack-cli globally through `npm i webpack-cli -g` and then run the `webpack` command directly from the console, it does work perfectly. That seemed suspicious. The error log, on the other hand, refered to a cygdrive/c/Users/Mariano/... folder despite the fact that such folder does not exist, the project folder was actually the same directory but starting with C:/Users/Mariano/...

Not to mention I'm NOT using cygwin but the command console. I have tinkered with cygwin and npm in the past, I think... but I reinstalled npm completely, clean cache and all (`npm -g rm`), even tried deleting the npm and npm-cache folders directly, reinstalled again, but the error persists.

Furthermore, the error is consistent with other commands from other packages, like babel. Again, I create a barebones babel.js test setup, install babel-core, babel-cli, a preset (babel-preset-es2015), all locally, then add `"build":"babel app.js -o bundle.js --presets es2015"` to package.json scripts, (create some app.js file with random code if you want in the project folder). In the console, run `npm run build`, aaaand, again, the same. I'll omit direct console log (it's almost identical) and just show you the full log file for this one:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'build' ]
2 info using npm@6.4.1
3 info using node@v10.13.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
5 info lifecycle babel_example@1.0.0~prebuild: babel_example@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle babel_example@1.0.0~build: babel_example@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle babel_example@1.0.0~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle babel_example@1.0.0~build: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\Mariano\Desktop\Pruebas\babel_example\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Files\cpp\bin\Intel64;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\PostgreSQL\pg96\bin;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\Mariano\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\;C:\Users\Mariano\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\;C:\Users\Mariano\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Mariano\AppData\Roaming\npm
9 verbose lifecycle babel_example@1.0.0~build: CWD: C:\Users\Mariano\Desktop\Pruebas\babel_example
10 silly lifecycle babel_example@1.0.0~build: Args: [ '-c', 'babel main.js -o bundle.js --presets es2015' ]
11 silly lifecycle babel_example@1.0.0~build: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle babel_example@1.0.0~build: Failed to exec build script
13 verbose stack Error: babel_example@1.0.0 build: `babel main.js -o bundle.js --presets es2015`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:182:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:962:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:251:5)
14 verbose pkgid babel_example@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\Mariano\Desktop\Pruebas\babel_example
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "build"
18 verbose node v10.13.0
19 verbose npm  v6.4.1
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error babel_example@1.0.0 build: `babel main.js -o bundle.js --presets es2015`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the babel_example@1.0.0 build script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

...What's going on? Does my previous messing with cygwin have anything to do with this? Something with PATH environment variables? I also tried changing npm version, I was using npm v.6.4.1, tried updating to npm@latest (currently v6.8.0)... no dice. It's driving me mad! ...any ideas?

Comment: If tou found a solution, please post it as an answer rather than including it in the question!

Comment: Ok, thank you. I've done that. :)

Answer (score 0):

Rolling back to npm v3.10.10 solves the problem. If anyone gets the same issue, do that. Try other versions too, anything previous npm v6.x.x, I haven't tried them yet. I will update this answer as I figure out in which version of npm the bug was introduced, and why does it affect me particularly.

I'll post it as an issue in npm's github for now. I'll keep you updated.